# Jquery File upload error when submitting to ashx

Tags: c#, jquery, file-upload, httphandler

I am attempting to use the [Jquery file upload](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) addon to asynchronously upload files to a C3 http handler.  I have gone through the setup steps on the [GitHub site](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup) for the project.  It seems to work fine in Firefox but throws a javascript error in IE ('Exception thrown and not caught'. Line 95, Char 25, File: test.html), even though the file is successfully uploaded.  I think my issue is related to the response of my ashx.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the body of the html for my page (test.html):

```
<form id="file_upload" action="testupload.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
    <button>Upload</button>
    <div>Upload files</div>
</form>
<table id="files"></table>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script>
/*global $ */
$(function () {
    $('#file_upload').fileUploadUI({
        uploadTable: $('#files'),
        downloadTable: $('#files'),
        buildUploadRow: function (files, index) {
            return $('<tr><td>' + files[index].name + '<\/td>' +
                    '<td class="file_upload_progress"><div><\/div><\/td>' +
                    '<td class="file_upload_cancel">' +
                    '<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Cancel">' +
                    '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel">Cancel<\/span>' +
                    '<\/button><\/td><\/tr>');
        },
        buildDownloadRow: function (file) {
            return $('<tr><td>' + file.name + '<\/td><\/tr>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the code in my ashx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;


namespace Testing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    public class TestUpload : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpPostedFile fileupload = context.Request.Files[0];


            string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.FileName);
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileupload.FileName).ToLower();
            string strSaveLocation = context.Server.MapPath("Upload") + "\\" + strFileName;
            fileupload.SaveAs(strSaveLocation);

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"" + fileupload.FileName + "\",\"type\":\"" + fileupload.ContentType + "\",\"size\":\"" + fileupload.ContentLength + "\"}");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops...The JS error is 'Exception thrown and not caught'.  Line 95, Char 25.  I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working...

First, I tried using hardcoded values for the name, type, and size responses and found it worked.  Here is what I used:

```
context.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"test\",\"size\":\"12345\"}");
```

I then noticed that fileupload.FileName was giving the full path of the file and assumed that was the problem.  When I change fileupload.FileName to strFileName in my response.write line, it works successfully in both Firefox and IE.  Here is a line that works:

```
context.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"" + strFileName + "\",\"type\":\"" + fileupload.ContentType + "\",\"size\":\"" + fileupload.ContentLength + "\"}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
context.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"" + fileupload.FileName + "\",\"type\":\"" + fileupload.ContentType + "\",\"size\":\"" + fileupload.ContentLength + "\"}");
```

To this:

```
context.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"" + fileupload.FileName + "\", type:\"" + fileupload.ContentType + "\",size:\"" + fileupload.ContentLength + "\"}");
```

Your object that you were passing back was just malformed.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried that change but it doesn't fix the error.  It also breaks Firefox.

Comment: It's a very unhelpful IE javascript error - I think I traced it back to a line in jquery.min.  In the meantime, I played around a bit with the response from the ashx and found the solution.  I'll post it as an answer.  Thanks for your help!