# query.Fileupload-ui error exception thrown but not caught

Tags: java, internet-explorer, file-upload

this is the same problem i am facing [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081119/jquery-file-upload-error-when-submitting-to-ashx)

it works fine in chrome,firefox but not in IE...the error is " IE ('Exception thrown and not caught'. Line 95, Char 25')"

from the reference i came to know that the error is in object writer.write

java code:(is it malformed): can anyone debug the error in this

`writer.write("{\"name\":\"" + item.getName()
                                        + "\",\"type\":\"" + item.getContentType()
                                        + "\",\"size\":\"" + item.getSize()
                                        + "\",\"filepath\":\"" + tp2 + "\"}");`

js:

```
        $(function () {
        var initFileUpload = function (suffix) {

            $('#file_upload').fileUploadUI({
                namespace: 'file_upload_' + suffix,
                fileInputFilter: '#file_' + suffix,
                dropZone: $('#drop_zone_' + suffix),
                uploadTable: $('#files_' + suffix),
                downloadTable: $('.display-frame'),
                buildUploadRow: function (files, index) {
                    return $('<tr><td>' + files[index].name

                    + '<td class="file_upload_cancel">' + '<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Cancel">' + '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel">Cancel<\/span>' + '<\/button><\/td><\/tr>');
                },
                buildDownloadRow: function (file) {
                    //  return $('<tr><td>' + file.name +   file.filepath +'<\/td><\/tr>');     
                    var path = '<div class="picthumb" id="pic" url="' + file.filepath + '" onclick="clickpick(this)"><div class="mainpic"><img src="';
                    path += file.filepath + '" class="uploader-thumb-img" style="width: 108px; height: 120px; top: 0px; left: 0px; "/></div></div>';
                    return $(path);
                }
            });
        };
        initFileUpload(1);

    });
```

the error IE showing is callback()

```
 if (typeof callBack === func) {
       try {
                            callBack();
           } catch (e) {
                            // Fix endless exception loop:
                            $(this).stop();
                            throw e;
                       }
           }
```

Comment: i found that the error is defintely with object writer is malfunction by hardcoding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with writer object for some reason item.getname was filename.jpg in chrome
and c:/images/filename.jpg in IE so i removed item.getname which was not needed

```
writer.write("{\",\"type\":\"" + item.getContentType() + "\",\"size\":\"" + item.getSize() + "\",\"filepath\":\"" + tp2 + "\"}");
```